# How to include \Rightarrow in equations

Tags: equations, flalign, xrightarrow

I want to introduce \Rightarrow in the equation, but "! Missing } inserted }".

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{flalign}

\rho = \frac{1}{\sigma} = \frac{m_0^{*}\cdot v_F}{N_0\cdot q_0^{2}\cdot \tilde{l} } = 
\frac{ 9,1 \cdot 10^{-31}\cdot 1,38}{5,86\cdot 10^{28}\cdot (1,6\cdot10^{-19})^{2}\cdot525 }  
$\Rightarrow$ $\rho = 20,65  [n\si{\ohm}m]$

\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are missing `\begin{document}` and remove the `$` and blank line `falign` is already math mode

Comment: Plus `\si` is not defined by default, I'd suggest you load the `siunitx` package and rather than `\si{\ogm}m` use `\SI{20.65}{\ohm\meter}`. Besides why `flalign` and not just `align` or even just `equation` as there is no linebreaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I'd write the example. I've wrapped all decimal numbers (except the one with unit) in `\num` to ensure its formatting is correct (just using $1,12$ the spacing around the comma is not decimal spacing but punctuation spacing). Also note how `\num` (and `\SI`) supports scientific notaiton, much less typing)

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  locale=DE, % use comma not . as the decimal
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\rho = \frac{1}{\sigma} &= \frac{m_0^{*}\cdot v_F}{N_0\cdot q_0^{2}\cdot \tilde{l} } = 
\frac{ \num{9,1e-31}\cdot \num{1,38}}{\num{5,86e28}\cdot
  (\num{1,6e-19})^{2}\cdot525 }
\\
\Rightarrow \rho &= \SI{20,65}{\ohm\meter}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```